# Understand min(points, key=lambda p: (p.x, p.y))

Tags: python

This code suppose to find smallest left point. I am not sure how to understand how the lambda function works. Please help!

Comment: For a basic class, there's no sense of "order" defined on the class. However, there is a sense of order in tuples: (1, 0) is less than (1, 3) which is less than (2, 0). This is called lexicographic ordering (order by the 1st element, then by the 2nd, and so on, like a dictionary). So what the key function does in this case is tell `min` what values from your object to use---the x and y coordinates, and stuffs them into a tuple so that `min()` will take the smallest element by lexicographic order. The lambda is just a version of `def f(p): return (p.x, p.y)` but defined in-line.

Comment: So it finds the point with the smallest `.x`, and if there are multiple points with that `.x`, it "breaks the tie" by returning one with the smallest `.y`.

Answer (score 0):

*Lambda functions are anonymous function, they work exactly in same way a function works.*

for example:

```
def add_two(a, b):
    return(a+b)

print(add_two(2,3))
```

output

```
5
```

Now we can write the same thing in lambda way

```
lambda(a,b): a+b
```